# Figure and subfigure of tikz-feynman is not at appropriate position

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tikz-feynman

I am using tikz-feynman to draw Feynman diagram which align as 2x2 subfigure.

However, the position of figure and subfigure compare with caption is very strange as in picture

[image: My result]

This is part of my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\feynmandiagram[large, horizontal=a to b]{
i1[particle=\(\overline d\)]--[fermion]a--[fermion, edge label'=\(\alpha\),momentum=\(p+k\)]b--[fermion, momentum=\(p\)]f1[particle=\(s\)],
i2[particle=\(\overline s\)]--[anti fermion, momentum'=\(p\)]c--[anti fermion, edge label=\(\beta\), rmomentum'=\(k\)]d--[anti fermion]f2[particle=\(d\)],
{[same layer]a--[photon, edge label=\(W\), rmomentum'=\(p+k\)]c},
{[same layer]b--[photon, edge label'=\(W\), momentum=\(k\)]d},
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\feynmandiagram[large, horizontal=a to b]{
i1[particle=\(\overline d\)]--[fermion]a--[fermion, edge label'=\(\alpha\),momentum=\(p+k\)]b--[fermion, momentum=\(p\)]f1[particle=\(s\)],
i2[particle=\(\overline s\)]--[anti fermion, momentum'=\(p\)]c--[anti fermion, edge label=\(\beta\), rmomentum'=\(k\)]d--[anti fermion]f2[particle=\(d\)],
{[same layer]a--[photon, edge label=\(W\), rmomentum'=\(p+k\)]c},
{[same layer]b--[scalar, edge label'=\(H\), momentum=\(k\)]d},
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\feynmandiagram[large, horizontal=a to b]{
i1[particle=\(\overline d\)]--[fermion]a--[fermion, edge label'=\(\alpha\),momentum=\(p+k\)]b--[fermion, momentum=\(p\)]f1[particle=\(s\)],
i2[particle=\(\overline s\)]--[anti fermion, momentum'=\(p\)]c--[anti fermion, edge label=\(\beta\), rmomentum'=\(k\)]d--[anti fermion]f2[particle=\(d\)],
{[same layer]a--[scalar, edge label=\(H\), rmomentum'=\(p+k\)]c},
{[same layer]b--[scalar, edge label'=\(H\), momentum=\(k\)]d},
};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\feynmandiagram[large, horizontal=a to b]{
i1[particle=\(\overline d\)]--[fermion]a--[fermion, edge label'=\(\alpha\),momentum=\(p+k\)]b--[fermion, momentum=\(p\)]f1[particle=\(s\)],
i2[particle=\(\overline s\)]--[anti fermion, momentum'=\(p\)]c--[anti fermion, edge label=\(\beta\), rmomentum'=\(k\)]d--[anti fermion]f2[particle=\(d\)],
{[same layer]a--[scalar, edge label=\(H\), rmomentum'=\(p+k\)]c},
{[same layer]b--[photon, edge label'=\(W\), momentum=\(k\)]d},
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Box diagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How to solve this one?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code snippet looks ok to me, so I guess the problem lies somewhere either before, after or at the dots. It can for example depend on the document class, included packets or how you have written the figures. As it given now it is more a guessing game to say where. Please, extend the code to a minimal compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, in such a way that it clearly shows the problem. Then it is possible to dig deeper to see what is going on, and you can get an answer.

Comment: @StefanH I have added all of my packages already.

Comment: The minimal working example should be a fully fledged but *minimal* example that replicates the issue;  I should be able to copy-paste it into a new file and see the error.  Unfortunately, what you have provided is not minimal (there are packages used which aren't relevant), nor is it working (it lacks `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.  I have tried recreating the issue on my end, but to no avail.

Comment: @JP-Ellis I have edited already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I'd like to say that it's really great to see the package I created being put to good use!  These diagrams look great :D

Now, about the issue you were having, it was because you have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \feynmandiagram {...};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The `\feynmandiagram` command actually creates its own Ti*k*Z environment and thus should *not* be used within a `{tikzpicture}` environment.  You are creating Ti*k*Z pictures within Ti*k*Z pictures which is generally not a good idea.  The intent of `\feynmandiagram` is that it is a standalone command just for Feynman diagrams.

If you wanted to add more fancy annotations in Ti*k*Z, or have the Feynman diagrams as just one component of a larger Ti*k*Z picture, or even need to place vertices manually, then the procedure is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  <other TikZ commands>
  \begin{feynman}
    \diagram {...};
    <other Feynman and/or TikZ commands>
  \end{feynman}
  <other TikZ commands>
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Notice that there is an additional `{feynman}` environment inside the `{tikzpicture}` and the command for the diagram is `\diagram` and not `\feynmandiagram`.

So, here is your fixed MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \feynmandiagram [large, horizontal=a to b] {
      i1 [particle=\(\overline d\)]
        -- [fermion] a
        -- [fermion, edge label'=\(\alpha\), momentum=\(p+k\)] b
        -- [fermion, momentum=\(p\)] f1[particle=\(s\)],
      i2 [particle=\(\overline s\)]
        -- [anti fermion, momentum'=\(p\)] c
        -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(\beta\), rmomentum'=\(k\)] d
        -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=\(d\)],
      {[same layer]
        a -- [photon, edge label=\(W\), rmomentum'=\(p+k\)] c
      },
      {[same layer]
        b -- [photon, edge label'=\(W\), momentum=\(k\)] d
      },
    };
    \caption{\(WW\) box diagram}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \feynmandiagram [large, horizontal=a to b] {
      i1 [particle=\(\overline d\)]
        -- [fermion]a--[fermion, edge label'=\(\alpha\), momentum=\(p+k\)] b
        -- [fermion, momentum=\(p\)]f1[particle=\(s\)],
      i2 [particle=\(\overline s\)]
        -- [anti fermion, momentum'=\(p\)] c
        -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(\beta\), rmomentum'=\(k\)] d
        -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=\(d\)],
      {[same layer]
        a -- [photon, edge label=\(W\), rmomentum'=\(p+k\)] c
      },
      {[same layer]
        b -- [scalar, edge label'=\(H\), momentum=\(k\)] d
      },
    };
    \caption{\(WH\) box diagram}
  \end{subfigure}
  \newline
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \feynmandiagram [large, horizontal=a to b] {
      i1 [particle=\(\overline d\)]
        -- [fermion]a--[fermion, edge label'=\(\alpha\),momentum=\(p+k\)] b
        -- [fermion, momentum=\(p\)]f1[particle=\(s\)],
      i2 [particle=\(\overline s\)]
        -- [anti fermion, momentum'=\(p\)] c
        -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(\beta\), rmomentum'=\(k\)] d
        -- [anti fermion]f2[particle=\(d\)],
      {[same layer]
        a -- [scalar, edge label=\(H\), rmomentum'=\(p+k\)] c
      },
      {[same layer]
        b -- [scalar, edge label'=\(H\), momentum=\(k\)] d
      },
    };
    \caption{\(HH\) box diagram}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \feynmandiagram [large, horizontal=a to b] {
      i1 [particle=\(\overline d\)]
        -- [fermion] a
        -- [fermion, edge label'=\(\alpha\), momentum=\(p+k\)] b
        -- [fermion, momentum=\(p\)] f1 [particle=\(s\)],
      i2[particle=\(\overline s\)]
        -- [anti fermion, momentum'=\(p\)] c
        -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(\beta\), rmomentum'=\(k\)] d
        -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=\(d\)],
      {[same layer]
        a -- [scalar, edge label=\(H\), rmomentum'=\(p+k\)] c
      },
      {[same layer]
        b -- [photon, edge label'=\(W\), momentum=\(k\)] d
      },
    };
    \caption{\(HW\) box diagram}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Box diagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Just a small remark, you can use spaces and newlines to make the code a little more legible; Ti*k*Z-Feynman (and Ti*k*Z) don't really care (much).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!!! Your package is really cool and useful. I think I have to use it for a long time :)